# Get path of a file without it's name

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, path

The file song.mp3 is located in

```
C:\x-folders\y-folder\z-folder\song.mp3
```

How can I store this path in a variable?

```
C:\x-folders\y-folder\z-folder\
```

Thank you

Comment: Study `FOR /?` output, especially for `%~dpI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this from the command line and I'll put two I can think of below for you to reference and test with when you get a chance. I'll include additional resources for further study too.

### Example One

```
for %a in ("C:\x-folders\y-folder\z-folder\song.mp3") do set var=%~dpa
```

Then `%var%` will be the set variable so just reference `%var%` for the applicable value.

---

### Example Two

If you need to iterate through some folder with many `.mp3` files then you can use this syntax

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b "C:\SomeFolder\*.mp3"') do set var=%~fa\
```

Then `%var%` will be the set variable so just reference `%var%` for the applicable value. You can reference `!var!` like that if you need to [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) depending on what exactly you need to accomplish with the loop if this is the way you plan to reference many files and their residing folder path. Lastly, you can use `dir /s /b` to traverse the directory recursively as well.

---

### Further Resources

- [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

  > **Variable Substitutions (FOR /?)**
  >
  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
  > %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
  > ```
- [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

  > *Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be
  >   expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is
  >   turned on with the SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion command.*
  >
  > ---
  >
  > *When delayed expansion is in effect, variables can be immediately read
  >   using !variable_name! you can also still read and use %variable_name%
  >   that will show the initial value (expanded at the beginning of the
  >   line).*

Comment: Very informative answer. 